# frontend not working after update to 2.4.6

Tags: frontend, magento2.4.6

I have a development website that consists in a migration from 2.45  to 2.4.6. I upgraded all modules to latest version and my backend is working perfectly. However, frontend gives blank page and I get a 524 error from cloudflare.
I tried to use Luma or even Blank theme, same result.
As I have full access to the server, do you have any ideas or clues ?
I tried to set up debugging, but nothing seems to happen :/
TIA for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. I would try looking the php error log of he server or the logs of magneto , system.log and exception.log. Here is a link to help you find the php error log [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel)
2. Try adding to the hosts file the ip of the server and point it to the website domain, so that you bypass cloudflair. With that you will see what error you get from server on the browser.
3. Another tip is to run `bin/magento set:di:compile` to see if you get some error there.

I believe from the error log of web server you will get your answer although if not , you can also disable all custom modules and again change to luma and run  `bin/magento setup:upgrade` to see if the problem persists.

Comment: No errors on compilation. Coudflare bypassed, but same issue. NOTHING on any error log (magento / nginx / php) :(

Comment: Have you checked if the domain targets the correct ip, check if you add a plain file in the root folder like ```test.php``` and add something like ```<?php echo 'test' ?>```  and browse it from the browser like  ```htttps://youtdomain.com/test.php``` . With this you will know for sure that your request reaches your route folder.

Comment: I can access admin URL (and everything works in admin :( ). If I create a php file I get a 404 error (from Magento) it seems routing is broken, but where to start looking for ?

Comment: Well the 500 errors are from server, so something is wrong with the webserver or with php. Try uncommenting in the ```app/bootstrap.php:14 file ``` the line ```#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Try fixing the file permissions have a look here ```https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-500-error/```

Comment: Have a look also here there where a github issue regarding 500 error on the frontend , maybe that is the problem ```https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37208```

Comment: It's not a 500 error that is thrown (I wish) it's just the Frontend looping till timeout...

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the error?

Answer (score 0):

copy `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/authentication-popup.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/{your-template}/Magento_Customer/templates/account/authentication-popup.phtml`
And remove:

```
<?php if ($viewModel->isGlobalScopeEnabled()): ?>
  ,
  "Magento_Customer/js/customer-global-session-loader": {}
<?php endif; ?>
```